# Autohotkey regular expression to strip html tags in multiple lines

Tags: regex, autohotkey

I have the following tag in the html file from which I need to grap only the text "XX(1119601.1)" using autohotkey and regular expression. Since the closing tag appears only after few line breaks I couldnt get the text between the tags.

```
       <dd class="call_number">
      <!-- holdings allowed -->
    XX(1119601.1)

       </dd>
```

Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Dont try to parse HTML with regex

Answer (score 0):

```
txt =
(Ltrim
    <dd class="call_number">
       <!-- holdings allowed -->
    XX(1119601.1)
    </dd>
)

RegexMatch(txt, "<dd .+?>(.*)</dd>", m)
msgbox % RegexReplace(m1, "<!.+>")
```

This code first matches everything within tags (you can make it a bit more specific, like only matching strings in  tags) then replaces Html comments.

You can remove unwanted newlines with RegexReplace as well.

**Edit:**
Changed RegexMatch to not automatically remove newlines.